# Frequently getting "An error has occurred - please retry your request" while voting on posts

Tags: bug, voting, error-message

Recently, I've been getting this error frequently and I have to refresh page to vote again. Is this happening to anyone else?

[image: "An error has occurred - please retry your request"]

It would be nice if it would retry automatically when this error happens (or let me vote again without having to refresh the page).

Comment: Happens to me very often! Especially when I'm accessing the site with a slow internet connection. My best guess: some timeouts happen too fast.